# How to navigate to Parametrised Constructor in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I want to navigate from one page to another.
If my destination page constructor is defined like ,

```
    public Bills()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
```

For normal navigation I am using

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Billing.Bills));
```

and its working fine. suppose if my destination page constructor is containing some parameters like ,

```
    public Bills(string strBillType, string strExchangeAmount, RootObject objRoot, string strPaymentType)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
```

in above situation **how can I navigate to the destination page?**.

Comment: @AndriiKrupka you are right I have searched but did n't found this one

Comment: I guess you searched with incorrect request.

Comment: Might be any how thanks for your help @AndriiKrupka

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use overload method `Navigate(Type sourcePageType, System.Object parameter)`

Create you class for parameters:

```
    public class BillParameters
    {
        //your properties
        public BillParameters(string strBillType, string strExchangeAmount, RootObject objRoot, string strPaymentType)
        {

        }
    }
```

Pass your parameters:

```
    var parameters = new BillParameters(strBillType, strExchangeAmount, objRoot, strPaymentType);
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Billing.Bills), parameters);
```

and retrive on your destination page

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var parameters = e.Parameter as BillParameters;
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank You @Andrii Krupka

Comment: A nice clear answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. If you need to send a value to your page, use the overload of [`Frame.Navigate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx):

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Billing.Bills), parameter)
```

You can then retrieve the value of the parameter from your page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Read e.Parameter to retrieve the parameter
}
```