# How to pass parameters to the constructor through Frame.Navigate in C++/WinRT?

Tags: winui-3, c++-winrt, windows-app-sdk

I just tried to use box_value, but it seems that the non-parameterized constructor will be always called. After I deleted the default constructor, XamlUserType::ActivateInstance() just  crashed with null pointer exception.

[How to navigate to Parametrised Constructor in UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649837/how-to-navigate-to-parametrised-constructor-in-uwp)

I found a C# version of solution to this problem, but I'm not sure what is the equivalent way in C++/WinRT.

Comment: Is it UWP or WinUI3? They are *not* the same technology, and you should show your C# solution, it maybe translatable.

Comment: It's a WinUI 3 application. I passed the parameter [here](https://github.com/ACGNnsj/WinUI3CppWinRTDemo/blob/61eb2a6a062370808a8768bbadd297b0deed3bc2/OCR/NavigationPage.xaml.cpp#LL61C9-L61C9), and deleted the default constructor [here](https://github.com/ACGNnsj/WinUI3CppWinRTDemo/blob/61eb2a6a062370808a8768bbadd297b0deed3bc2/OCR/ConfigPage.idl#L10).

Comment: As the linked answer calls out, the parameter arrives not through the constructor but through the OnNavigatingTo and OnNavigatedTo arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've taken that as some kind of custom function, and thus didn't think much about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Raymond Chen said, you need to get your parameters in `OnNavigatedTo`.
You can refer to the following code.

```
//ConfigPage.xaml.h

void OnNavigatedTo(Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Navigation::NavigationEventArgs const&);
 
//ConfigPage.xaml.cpp

void ConfigPage::OnNavigatedTo(Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Navigation::NavigationEventArgs const& e)
{
   auto window = unbox_value<Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Window>(e.Parameter());     
}
```

Comment: Yeah, and I find that Window itself inherits from IInspectable, so it doesn't need boxing.